# How to search date column via index, not via filter?

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

three is date column, oscar_alpha is integer.

I have this [result](http://explain.depesz.com/s/slj)  from Postgres explain. On 16 row I want to prevent acces to table to find in filter condition

```
Filter: ((three >= '15.04.2010 00:00'::date) AND (three <= '15.04.2016 00:00'::date) AND (oscar_alpha = 341)).
```

And I want to check this condition via indexes.
I created indexes:

```
create index index1 on table_name (three , oscar_alpha);
create index index2 on table_name (three);
create index index3 on table_name (oscar_alpha);
```

But they are not using.

Yes, some data anonymised.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a composite index on `(oscar_alpha, three)`, in that order.

An index is sorted in lexicographic order, first on the value of the first column, then, that being equal, on the second etc, like a phonebook: surnames first, then names.

It's easy to get all Smiths from John to Mary from a phonebook, but not that easy to get all Johns from Jones to Smith, because the entries are ordered on surname first.

Same with your query: if you order on `oscar_alpha` first, all values with the same `oscar_alpha` go in `three` order, and it's possible to apply a range condition to them.

Comment: I added a composite index on (oscar_alpha, three), but it`s not workiing

Comment: @Usm: oh I see. You want a composite index on `quebec_seven, oscar_alpha, three`.

Comment: @Usm: unfortunately, there's not much I can do without seeing the data and the query.